# Should i keep more code in controller or in helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In My project, I have scenarios where in a controller action i need to do a lot of dependent stuff which can not be moved to model directly. To keep the controller skinny, i end up moving that code to helper. Is this a good practice?

For example, in a controller action, i need to do verify the checksum of the request first, then make entries in two tables, then call some external api and according to the result update some values. I end up moving the call to external api to a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good practice? definitely not! Not only will it make code maintenance a bummer of a task, it'll also make testing difficult.

There's never a scenario where logic cannot be moved from a controller. In general for any Object Orientated language, a project should be based on the MVC pattern at the very least to separate business logic from presentation.

Based on your example, something simple can easily delegate individual responsibility to specialist classes, thus removing the logic from the controller.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    handler = FooHandler.new(params[:foos])
    foo = handler.process_foo

    if foo[:result]
      flash[:success] = 'Foo was successful'
      redirect_to foo_path
    else
      flash[:error] = foo[:errors]
      redirect_to foo_path
    end
  end
end

class FooHandler
  delegate :valid_checksum?, to: :checksum_klass
  delegate :create_foos, to: :foo_klass
  delegate :call_foo_api, to: :foo_api_klass

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def process_foo
    return {result: false, errors: 'failed checksum'} unless valiid_checksum?
    return {result: false, errors: 'failed to create the foos' unless create_foos
    return {result: false, errors: 'api errors'} unless call_foo_api
    {result: true}
  end

  private
  attr_accessor :params

  def checksum_klass
    @checksum_klass ||= ChecksumChecker.new(params[:checksum])
  end

  def checksum_klass
    @foo_klass ||= FooCreator.new(params[:foo_objects])
  end

  def checksum_klass
    @foo_api_klass ||= FooApiHandler.new(params[:foo_objects])
  end
end
```

The above style of implementation is an example of how you could start to split each individual process into their own class, which runs through the single FooHandler class, decoupling all the logic from the controller. All the controller is concerned with in this example is whether or not the process was successful.

My example works on the basis that each action is contained within its own class, so the FooHandler can delegate responsibility to that class when it needs to, passing on some data and washing its hands of any responsibility. All it cares about is the result.

It all boils down to your understanding of patterns. The two most helpful patterns I use (besides Rubys duck typing and delegation) is the observer pattern and decorator pattern.

The observer pattern would allow you to associate dependent processes with the state of the observable class. So for your example, if the API call is dependent on the objects being created, try setting up a FooCreationHandler that has an FooApiHandler as a subscribed listener. If the handler is successful in creating the records, it can then notify the FooApiHandler that it's ok to call the external APIs- thus decoupling the dependency.

Patterns like the decorator would allow you to 'decorate' objects with specific behavior when you need it, rather than having a big, convoluted if statement and 'knowledge' of other classes. Again, this is a good pattern at allowing you to create specialist classes with abstract behavior, rather than containing logic to one class or the controller.

Hope this brief example helps.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a good practice?

**Nope**. Helpers are for view-specific stuff only. Currency formatting, date formatting, wrapping things in a specific `<div>`, that kind of stuff.  By default, they're not even available in controllers. You have to require them explicitly.

Orchestrating cooperation of multiple moving parts should not be in helper. And yes, controller is not a good place either. Me, I usually place this kind of logic in a ServiceObject or something. So my controllers usually look like this:

```
class ProjectsController < AppicationController
  def create
    # this will create the project, create associated objects, push notifications to 
    # whatever needs to be notified, etc. 
    ::ServiceObjects::Project::Create.new(project_params)
    # render something
  end

  ...
end
```

This way, your controllers remain skinny. And as an added bonus, service objects are much easier to test.